# "Unknown response received from cvs server" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssh, cvs

I've been using Eclipse with CVS over SSH for some time with no problems.

Today, Eclipse started complaining with:

> unknown response received from cvs server

whenever I try to do any CVS operations.

What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution!

It turns out that my SSH password had expired, and needed to be changed. I simply logged in to the target server over SSH, changed the password, and then updated my Eclipse CVS configuration to use the new password.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me, when the CVS project moved to a new server.  The server's ssh fingerprint changed (of course, because it's a new server, duh), and every thing I tried to do in Eclipse just got the null failure explained above.  To fix it, I had to go into the preferences (path: window/preferences/network/ssh2/knownhosts) and delete the fingerprint of the old server, and then retry the connection.  New fingerprint came up for validation, accepted it by typing yes, and it was all good after that.  I wish Eclipse's error messages were just a bit more verbose.
Cheers,
Zistrosk